# Question about calculation the equality of Hamiltonian vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

In McDuff&Salamon's Book, they claimed that since $X_{g^{-1}\xi g}=\psi^*_g X_\xi$,  hence the functions $H_{g^{-1}\xi g}$ and  $\psi^*_g H_\xi$  generate the same Hamiltonian vector field.

Here, $\iota(X_ξ)ω = dH_ξ$, below is my calculation, I wonder what is my fault.

> By the definition, $\iota(X_{g^{-1}\xi g})\omega=dH_{g^{-1}\xi g}$.
> Assume $\iota(Y)\omega=d\psi^*_g H_\xi$, then
>
> $X_{g^{-1}\xi g}=Y$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $dH_{g^{-1}\xi g}=d\psi^*_g H_\xi$
>
> $\Leftrightarrow$ $\iota(X_{g^{-1}\xi g})\omega=d\psi^*_g H_\xi$
>
> $\Leftrightarrow$ $\iota(\psi^*_g X_\xi)\omega=d\psi^*_g H_\xi$.
>
> Now we verify the last equation:
>
> we have known that $\iota(X_\xi)\omega=dH_\xi$, then
>
> $\psi^*_gdH_\xi(Y)=\psi^*_g\iota(X_\xi)\omega(Y)=\iota(X_\xi)\omega(\psi_{*,g}Y)=\omega(X_\xi,\psi_{*,g}Y)=\psi^*_g\iota(\psi_{*,g^{-1}}X_\xi)\omega(Y)$,
>
> $(\psi^*_g dH_\xi)(Y)=d(\psi^*_g H_\xi)(Y)$,

So I can only get $\psi^*_g\iota(\psi_{*,g^{-1}}X_\xi)(Y)=(d\psi^*_g
 H_\xi)\omega(Y)$ (1), there is an additional $\psi^*_g$.

I wonder either my
calculation is wrong, or, we can earn conclude what we want (equality
of Hamiltonian vector field) from (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation could be somewhat simplified, but the only thing you need is to realize that
$$
(\psi_g^* dH_\xi)(Y) = dH_\xi(\psi_{g,*}Y) = d(H_\xi \circ \psi_g)(Y) = d(\psi_g^* H_\xi)(Y)
$$
and therefore $\psi_g^* dH = d(\psi_g^*H_\xi)$. The key fact is that **pullback acts on functions by composition from behind**.

**EDIT**:

*Assumption*: $X_{g^{-1}\xi g} = \psi_g^* X_\xi$ for all $g\in G$ acting by symplectomorphisms on $M$ and for all $\xi \in Lie(G)$.

*Statement*: then $H_{g^{-1}\xi g} = \psi_g^* H_\xi$.

*Proof*: the fundamental vector field $X_{g^{-1}\xi g}$ satisfies $\iota(X_{g^{-1}\xi g})\omega = d(H_{g^{-1}\xi g})$. Then, the assumption is equivalent to
$$
\iota(Y)d(H_{g^{-1}\xi g}) = \iota(Y)\left[\iota(\psi_g^*X)\omega \right]
$$
for all $Y$ vector field. The last is in turn equivalent to
$$
\iota(Y)d(H_{g^{-1}\xi g}) = \omega(\psi_g^*X,Y) \qquad (3)
$$
but by $G$-equivariance of $\omega$ we have that the RHS in the last equation can be rewritten as $\omega(X,\psi_{g^{-1}}^*Y)$ which is $\iota(\psi_{g^{-1}}^*Y)d(H_\xi)$. By the properties of pullbacks and pushforwards, this is
$$
\iota(\psi_{g^{-1}}^* Y)dH_\xi = \iota(Y)d(H_\xi \circ \psi_g)
$$
and thus from (3) we get
$$
\iota(Y)d(H_{g^{-1}\xi g})=\iota(Y)d(H_\xi \circ \psi_g)
$$
for all $Y$, and thus
$$
d(H_{g^{-1}\xi g})=d(H_\xi \circ \psi_g)
$$
Assuming $M$ is a connected manifold, if two functions have the same differential then they are equal up to a constant. If that constant can be chosen to be zero consistently for $\xi \in Lie(G)$, then $H_\cdot$ is called a moment map, which I suppose is introduced in McDuff & Salamon.
$$
H_{g^{-1}\xi g}=H_\xi \circ \psi_g = \psi_g^* H_\xi
$$

**Remark**: I have been sloppy with pushforwards because I assume $g$ are bijective symplectomorphisms, and everything works fine.

Comment: Could you please say more, I still can't understand the difference

Comment: The pullback of a function $H:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via $\psi_g: M \rightarrow M$ is *defined* by $\psi_g^*H(p) = H(\psi_g(p))$ for every point $p\in M$.

Comment: I know this, but I can not see how it can solve my problem, in fact, in my calculation,  I use this all the time.

Comment: Now that I read the question again I find it is slightly confusing: could you clarify what you assume and which equality you want to prove?

The McDuff & Salamon statement I have read: $X_{g^{-1}\xi g} = \psi_g^*X_\xi$ implies that $H_{g^{-1}\xi g}$ and $\psi_g^*H_\xi$ generate the same Hamiltonian vector field. Do you want to prove the equality between the X's or the implication stated by the authors?

Comment: Yes, it is. I try to prove it, but stuck, what I quoted is my calculation.

Comment: From your answer, and the text quoting your calculation **I understand that you want to prove that** $X_{g^{-1}\xi g} = \psi_g^* X_\xi$ . Gimme a second and I will expand my answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry no, that is not what I want to prove. What I want to prove is why they generate the same Hamiltonian vector field.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are so kink. Your answer is of great help to me reading this obscure book alone